# How to call function itself inside a function in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call the function itself within the function.

Basically it will call the function itself to make another request if the first request has the id.

I have something like

```
function test(variable) {
    var q = $q.defer();
    $http({
           method: 'get',
           url: 'myurl.com'
        }).then(function(returnData) {
            if(returnData.getNewInfo) {
                test(returnData.id).then(function(secondData){
                   q.resolve(secondData);
                })
            } else {
                   q.resolve(returnData)
            }    
        });            
    }
    return q.promise;
}
```

I am getting 
`test(...).then` is not a function error in the console on this line

```
 test(returnData.id).then(function(secondData){
```

I am trying to call the function itself inside the promise. Not sure how to fix my issue. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code indentation and you'll get the below - see my comment about the stray brace. So the function is returning undefined rather than `q.promise`.

```
function test(variable) {
    var q = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'myurl.com'
    }).then(function(returnData) {
        if (returnData.getNewInfo) {
            test(returnData.id).then(function(secondData) {
                q.resolve(secondData);
            })
        } else {
            q.resolve(returnData)
        }
    });
}  // <------- end of function - should be removed?

return q.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return your `$http` call. Promises are chainable and `$http` returns a promise.

```
function test(variable) {
    return $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'myurl.com'
    }).then(function (returnData) {
        if (returnData.getNewInfo) {
            return test(returnData.id);
        } else {
            return returnData;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function test(variable, callback) {
  /*snip*/
  callback();
  /*snip*/
}
test("foo",test);
```

Comment: Reason for my downvote - this is not solving a problem - it is replacing it. With more complex scenarios this will lead to a "callback hell".

Comment: yes @Kaspars probably not the best answer in the end. Looking through the other answers; the actual issue was a syntax error in the original code. In my experience converting to callbacks -at least temporarily- would could help flush out the actual problem.